# Logic and Generalizations

Tags: logic

As as logic student, I often encounter the following: a situation where a formal system can't see a generalization is true, but *I* can.

The usual case is that of  $\omega$-incompleteness. It is often the case that we have some formal theory T such that $T \vdash \psi(n)$ but $T \nvdash \forall n \psi(n)$ (where the quantifier ranges over natural numbers). Generalizing this, we can introduce the term of $ordinal-incompleteness$. This would be when $T \vdash \psi(\alpha)$ but $T \nvdash \forall \alpha \psi(\alpha)$, where the quantifier ranges over ordinals. Generalizing the generalized version (in an informal way), we can say $T$ is $P-incomplete$ if for every object $O$ with some property $P$, $T \vdash \psi(O)$, but $T \nvdash \forall O \psi(O)$, where the quantifier ranges over all objects $O$ with property $P$.

For an interesting example, I asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002935/what-goes-wrong-when-you-try-to-reflect-infinitely-many-formulas) , about why ZFC can't reflect infinitely many formulas, and hence itself. One of the primary reasons is distinguishing between:

(1) For any finite collection of formulas, ZFC proves that there is a set reflecting those formulas.

(2) ZFC proves that for any finite collection of formulas there is a set reflecting those formulas.

(1) is true but (2) is false. However, there is a clear sense that if (1) is true, (2) *should* be true. That is, if (1) is true, *we* can see that for any finite collection of formulas, there is a set reflecting those formulas, even though ZFC *can't* see that. We can then make some very interesting conclusions that ZFC can't it seems, like saying that we can see that there is some cardinal $\kappa$ with countable cofinality that provably exists in ZFC, such that $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC.

My question is as follows: does there exist a logic such that for any generalization that *I* can see, the logic can see it too (or, a bit more precisely, one that would satisfy the "generalized generalization" above)? If there is, why are mathematicians working with first-order logic when it has this clear deficiency that can be remedied? Or, for some mysterious reason, is it the case that for every logic, there is some generalization that I can draw but the logic can't? If so, is there any way to understand this in a non-magical way? It would seem pretty magical to me.

EDIT: So my first question above seems to be "no". I thought that maybe infinitary logics can help with capturing some generalizations, for example those that employ the [$\omega$-rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory#.CF.89-logic), but it seems pretty straightforward from Godelian reasons that if a logic could capture *all* generalizations then it would be inconsistent. So, I guess my question would become, are there any better logics that capture more generalizations than FOL yet are consistent (i.e. infinitary logics)? Is there anyway we can make mathematical progress in distinguishing those generalizations that a logic can capture consistently and those generalizations that a logic can't capture on pain of inconsistency? Can we do this *within* a logic? Also, my second original question still has force - why isn't our ability to draw generalizations, an ability that outstrips all possible formalized systems - not magical? Is this ability at all in tension with a reductionist, naturalist world view? (I apologize since this last question is primarily philosophical, but I think some mathematical insight can be helpful. I'll accept an answer that just addresses the first question.)

Comment: Sounds to me that you're looking for Feferman's extension of $\sf ZFC$. You add a constant symbol $M$ and the axioms that (1) $M$ is a countable transitive set; (2) the schema $\varphi\leftrightarrow\varphi^M$. Then $M$ is a countable transitive model of $\sf ZFC$. Surprisingly, this comes at no additional cost of consistency strength!

Comment: It's not clear to me that (2) _should_ be true. A random model of ZFC might have a quite wrong idea about what a "finite" collection is, such that (2) implies something about collections that can't _actually_ be reflected in that model. (Or at least, if they can, then that would be beyond what (1) tells us).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for that, I think that probably solves the specific example I gave, but do you see that as solving the general problem?

Comment: @HenningMakholm But isn't the fact that it has a wrong idea about what a finite collection is precisely the reason we want to rule it out? :)

Comment: @David: Alas, the dream of ruling it out was shattered by Gödel. A theory / proof system that can talk about arithmetic and allows "is this a valid proof?" to be decidable _must_ allow for models with non-standard integers in it. (Bla bla additional technical premises for Gödel's result which aren't really loopholes).

Comment: @Henning So, I'm not sure where that leaves your stance on the above problem. Are you saying, e.g., if $T \vdash \psi(n)$ then it isn't even desirable that $T \vdash \forall n \psi(n)$? So, it's not only the case that I can't "see" the truth of the latter, it's not even (intuitively) true that if $\psi(n)$ is true for all numbers n, then $\forall n \psi(n)$ is true?

Comment: @DavidBuiles: Desirable or not, Gödel's incompleteness theorem says it is not _possible_ (in any reasonable way) to get that for all $\psi$ that satisfies your premise. Concretely, $T\vdash \forall n.\psi(n)$ _necessarily_ fails if $\psi(n)$ is taken to be "$n$ is not a valid proof of the Gödel sentence for $T$".

Comment: Ah yes, I should have said if $T \vdash \psi(n)$ and we accept T is a true theory about numbers, sets, or whatever, then _we_ can see that $\forall n \psi (n)$ is true. It's not the case that we can see that $T$ proves this generalization, since in some cases it patently does not. But we can see the truth of the generalization nonetheless. I'll edit my question a bit

Comment: @DavidBuiles - I'm not sure I understand your question. I may be mistaken here, but it seems as if there are two different things at play. On the one hand, you seem to be looking for ways of strengthening a proof system (say, by adding a stronger inference rule), in order to be able to prove more things. On the other hand, by mentioning infinitary logics (e.g. $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$), you seem to be  worried with expressability, i.e. what concepts are definable in which logic. Did I read you wrongly?

Comment: @Nagase The reason I mentioned infinitary logics is that the $\omega$ - rule is a rule of inference that can only be used in proofs with infinitely many steps. So, we have to go beyond FOL to infinitary logics for the $\omega$ - rule to make any difference. Tangentially, I'm also worried about expressibility - it seems like the fact that FOL cannot express "is finite" is a major defect.

Comment: @DavidBuiles - I see. Well, I don't have much to add, except that: (i) as far as I understand the matter, although there are possible ways of strengthening our axiom system in order to capture more "truths" than before, Gödel's first theorem shows that the set of "truths" (so to speak) can't be effectively enumerated (still, you may want to check some stuff on proof-theoretical consistency proofs); (ii) about expressibility, the fact that FOL can't express "is countable" (for instance), while a defect of sorts, is also an advantage, as it allows us to study the more tractable countable...

Comment: (cont.)... models and then use (say) Löwenheim-Skolem-Tarski to "transfer" that property to other models. So there are advantages to FOL's lack of expressive power (in particular, LST, Compactness, interpolation, etc., are useful model-theoretic tools, which may be lost with added expressive power).